# Using np.where to find index of element in 2D array gives ValueError

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to use np.where to find the index of an element in an array, specifically row number

I have an array of say size 1000 x 6, named 'table'. The first element in each row is a 2 x 2 string array, and the rest are 0s. Eg. a 5 x 6 example of elements in 'table':

```
    [['s',' ']   0 0 0 0 0
     [' ',' ']]
    [[' ',' ']   0 0 0 0 0
     [' ','a']]
    [[' ',' ']   0 0 0 0 0
     [' ',' ']]         
    [['p',' ']   0 0 0 0 0
     [' ',' ']]
    [[' ',' ']   0 0 0 0 0
     ['b',' ']]
```

The 2x2 arrays are all different, and I want to get the index, in particular the row number, of the one containing a specific 2x2 in my large table.

Eg. say I have

```
    grid = [['s',' ']   
            [' ',' ']]
```

I would like my code to return [0][0]

I have tried this:

```
    i,j = np.where(table == grid)
```

and also

```
    i,j = np.where(np.all(table == grid))
```

and i get the following error:

```
    ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Using a single value eg.

```
    index = np.where(table == grid)
```

does not result in an error, but print(index) will output an empty array:

```
    (array([], dtype=int64),)
```

From similar questions on Stack Overflow I can't seem to figure out how this error applies to mine and I've been staring at it for ages

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of `table` say shape (8,6)?

Comment: If you substitute a single name for `i,j` what result do you get?

Comment: It also yields a Deprecation error: elementwise == comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.

Comment: So you have an ndarray, where each row contains a list and 5 ints?

Comment: I have edited including output for a single value

Comment: `table[:,0]` elements are lists or 2-d anumpy arrays?

Comment: Sorry that's my bad. They are numpy.ndarrays

Comment: Please, when asking about a complex array like this, be accurate as to which elements are arrays and which are lists.  And if possible provide an example that works with copy-n-paste.  Other wise it's a pain to recreate and test your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup:

```
b = np.array([['s','t'],['q','r']])
c = np.array([['s',' '],[' ',' ']])
a = np.array([[c,0,0,0,0,0],
              [c,0,0,0,0,0],
              [c,0,0,0,0,0],
              [c,0,0,0,0,0],
              [b,0,0,0,0,0],
              [c,0,0,0,0,0],
              [c,0,0,0,0,0],
              [c,0,0,0,0,0],
              [c,0,0,0,0,0]])
```

Assuming your only interested in *column* zero; write a function that will test each item in a one-d array. And apply it to column zero

```
def f(args):
    return [np.all(thing==b) for thing in args]

>>> np.apply_along_axis(f,0,a[:,0])
array([False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False])
>>>
```

Use np.where on the result

```
>>> np.where(np.apply_along_axis(f,0,a[:,0]))
(array([4], dtype=int64),)
```

Or following the note in the `numpy.where` docs:

```
>>> np.asarray(np.apply_along_axis(f,0,a[:,0])).nonzero()
(array([4], dtype=int64),)
```

---

As @hpaulj points out `np.apply_along_axis` is not necessary. so

```
>>> [np.all(thing == b) for thing in a[:,0]]
[False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False]

>>> np.asarray([np.all(thing == b) for thing in a[:,0]]).nonzero()
(array([4], dtype=int64),)
```

And without the Python iteration:

```
>>> (np.stack(a[:,0])==b).all(axis=(1,2))
array([False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False])

>>> (np.stack(a[:,0])==b).all(axis=(1,2)).nonzero()
(array([4], dtype=int64),)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Would you mind clarifying what the arguments are for the function: 
    def f(args):
    return [np.all(thing==b) for thing in args]? I'm not sure as I haven't seen this setup before

Comment: I understand that b is the particular grid I'm looking for, do I pass my large table in as args? Is thing merely a variable name?

Comment: Do you need the `apply_along_axis`?  `f(a[:,0])` works (returning a list rather than array).

Comment: `f(args)` just does a list comprension.  It just iterates through `args) (the first column), and tests each (2,2) array against `b`.

Comment: I see how it works now. Thanks very much to both of you

Comment: A non-iterative version of this test is: `(np.stack(a[:,0])==b).all(axis=(1,2))`.   For this small example it is faster than `f(a[:,0])`, but that needs to be verified with a larger case.  `np.stack` combines the (2,2) arrays into one (n,2,2) array,which is then tested against the (2,2) `b`.

Comment: @hpaulj - nice. I got stuck and couldn't see past `a[:,0].shape` being `(9,)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using vectorize

```
a = np.array( [np.array([['s',' '],[' ',' ']])  , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ])
grid = np.array([['s',' '],[' ',' ']]) 

vfunc = np.vectorize(lambda x: np.all(grid == x))
np.argwhere(vfunc(a))
```